# Standing in "fries" of me?

Tags: pronunciation, accent

In Christina Perri's song A Thousand Years, according to all lyrics websites at 1:46 the lyrics is "standing in front of me".

https://youtu.be/rtOvBOTyX00?t=106

But to my ear she clearly sings "in fries of me" which doesn't make sense, what did she sing actually?

Comment: She's singing "in front of me", a bit indistinctly.

Comment: It sounds to me like /frǝjnt/, which is very strange to my ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's saying "standing in front of me", as the lyrics say.

She either slightly mispronounces it (exhaling a little more air than she intended to) or the microphone distorted it a little, which makes the T slightly elongate and sound a bit like an S, which is where your ear is getting a little confused: but she's definitely singing "standing in front of me"

I'm fairly sure in this case that it's mostly due to bad mastering of the audio for this video: You can hear the same effect on other T and D sounds in the song, along with a "hiss" on S sounds, which become over-exaggerated and sound a little like static. If you listen to the album version of the song, her mispronunciation is still there, but it's far less obvious due to better audio

Comment: Youtube audio is often very compressed and poor quality compared to a CD or high bit rate mp3. It's definitely 'in front of me'.